# Find the non trivial solution to a matrix containing a complex number.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$
A = [B\mid b] = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
-3+i & -5 & 0 \\ 
2 & 3+i & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Find the non trivial solution to A. (Solving $B x = b$)

I fully understand the method of finding the non trivial solution of a matrix, however, with complex numbers within, I simply do not know where to start.

Comment: When you say solution, I assume you mean that is an augmented matrix representing a system?

Comment: Yes, I apologize, i simply do not know how to draw the line before the solution vector. So technically this is a homogeneous system.

Comment: No problem. Then you just find the RREF. Complex numbers are no stranger than real numbers and integers. Complex conjugate may help, but you just use complex number algebra to turn the matrix into RREF form. Like what row operations should you perform to make the 2 a zero and then -5 a zero and so on...assuming this equation had a unique solution. If it doesn't the RREF still works you just might get a complex vector space

Comment: @amundi12 Please choose braces of your taste and check the naming, is your $A$ the inner matrix (I named it $B$) or the augmented matrix (as ist now is)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start you off with finding the RREF of $A$, note that multiplying a complex number by its conjugate produces a real number. i.e., $(-3+i)(-3-i) = 9 +3i - 3i -i^{2} = 10.$

Take $(-3-i)$ of row 1.

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cc|c}10 & 15+5i&0\\
2& 3+i&0 \end{array} \right] $$